# get_term_link doesn't work

Tags: taxonomy

with the support of ACF team I created a page where I list the values from a Taxonomy Custom Field (custom field named cognome_nome) alphabetically.
I explain:

Term 1

- Name: Elena P
- slug: elena_p
- cognome_nome: P Elena

Term 2

- Name: Andrea B
- slug: andrea_b
- cognome_nome: B Andrea

The list will be:

- B Andrea
- P Elena

But how can I add the link to the term page? I tried with get_term_link( $term ) but It gives me the link of the last author I added to the taxonomy.

Here's my code:

```
$terms = get_terms( 'authors', $args );
$values = array();
foreach($terms as $term):

array_push($values, get_field('cognome_nome', $term));

endforeach;

sort($values);
// display values
foreach ($values as $value) {
echo "<div> <a href='" . get_term_link( $term ) . "'</a>" . get_field('cognome_nome', $term) . "</div>";
echo $value;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how ACF works or how its data is stored, but in general, I would just use `usort()` to sort the returned array of terms via the ACF value of `cognome_nome`. Note that `array_push` is a bit expensive to use, so try to avoid that ;-)

As I stated in comments, your code does not make much sense to me. You have two separate `foreach` loops, which is fine, but you are trying to use the value of the first `foreach` loop's value (*`$term`*) in the second one, which will not work. In a `foreach` loop, the value of the last key remains outside/after the `foreach` loop, which means that `$term` will always be set to the last term. Because of this, and because you use `$term` in your second `foreach` loop as is, all values will be set to the last term of your `$terms` object. That is exactly what you are seeing.

In general, this is how I would tackle this issue

```
$terms = get_terms( 'authors', $args );
/**
 * Remember the usort bug. Use @usort to cut the bug's wings and feet ;-)
 */
@usort( $terms, function ( $a, $b )
{
    /**
     * Get our ACF Data
     * Just make sure that my logic is correct here and that you actually get data from get_field
     */
    $array_a = get_field( 'cognome_nome', $a );
    $array_b = get_field( 'cognome_nome', $b );

    if ( $array_a ) {
        $sort_a = $array_a;
    } else {
        $sort_a = 'zzz'; //Kind of fall back to add posts without field last
    }

    if ( $array_b ) {
        $sort_b = $array_b;
    } else {
        $sort_b = 'zzz'; //Kind of fall back to add posts without field last
    }

    // Sort by these ACF data
    return strcasecmp ( $sort_a, $sort_b );
});
```

This will take care of sorting. You can just then loop through your terms normally and output them as you would normally do

Comment: Ok, everything's seems clear.. I thought it was wrong too using $term outside the first foreach loop. But I didn't know how to do correctly. ;)
So, this is too much for me.. eheh I have to add the foreach loop after your code? Doing `foreach ($terms as $term) { echo "<a href='" . get_term_link( $term ) . "'</a>" . get_field('cognome_nome', $term);`. Because I add the foreach and I can see all the terms (from cognome_nome) with the correct links, but they aren't sort alphabetically.. :( What am I doing wrong?

Comment: eheh it's ok! ;) Thank you. I would like to sort the cognome_nome values alphabetically. 
See my example above: Every term has a custom field (cognome_nome) and I would like to sort these values alphabetically. :)

Comment: Ok.. Anyway it works your new code!!! :D I tested better and I'll let you know!

Comment: YEAH!!!!! No problem, test thorouhgly and make sure it work as you expect it to work

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach ($values as $value) {
    echo "<div> <a href='" . get_term_link($value ) . "'</a>" . 
    get_field('cognome_nome', $term) . "</div>";
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but please explain how this code solves the problem.

Answer (score -2):

i thinks this function are used for get term link.

```
get_term_link($terms,texonomy_name);
```

this function is perfectly work.

Comment: The OP already mentions `get_term_link()`. Exactly how does mentioning that function qualify as an answer?